# Mongoose group data after populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema that holds messages between users:

```
const messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    message:{ type: String },
    sender: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    recipient: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
});
```

I am trying to:

- `.find()` all messages sent to a user
- `.populate()` the sender field from a `User` schema
- `.group()` messages by `sender.username` (`username` is populated from `User`)
- Only return the most recent (by date tag) message per sender

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
let inbox = [];
let usercount = {};

await Messages.find({recipient: req.params.id})
    .populate('sender')
    .sort({updatedAt: -1})
    .lean()
    .then(messages => {
        messages.forEach(message => {
            let m = {
                username: message.sender.username,
                message: message.message
            }
      if (!usercount[message.sender.username]) inbox.push(m);
      usercount[message.sender.username] = 1;
        })
    });

console.log(inbox);
```

Which gives me an array containing the most recent message sent by each `username`. However this requires two iterations: once over the entire message document and again over the the returned object.

Is there a way of achieving the same result using `.aggregate()` & `group`)?